# Dúvida sobre Sessões no CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-7

De acordo com :

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
```

A sessão vai ser destruída após 7200 segundos, no entanto eu queria saber se quando eu atualizo a pagina ou acesso outra pagina do meu sistema, esse tempo é renovado ? Caso não, existe alguma configuração na config do CI que faça isso ?

```
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;

'sess_time_to_update'
|
|   How many seconds between CI regenerating the session ID.
```

O que seria essa regeneração/renovação do id da session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A sessão vai ser destruída após 7200 segundos, no entanto eu queria
>   saber se quando eu atualizo a pagina ou acesso outra pagina do meu
>   sistema, esse tempo é renovado?
>   Caso não, existe alguma configuração na config do CI que faça isso ?
>   O que seria essa regeneração/renovação do id da session ?

Existe uma correlação nas duas perguntas onde `$config['sess_time_to_update']` significa a frequência da atualização da sessão, sendo que a cada 5 minutos isso ocorre (*configuração padrão*), gerando uma nova **ID** da sessão e redefinindo a configuração do vencimento da expiração da sessão com base na chave `$config['sess_expiration']`.

Usualmente configuramos de outra forma:

```
$config['sess_expiration']  = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
```

onde a `'sess_expiration'` configurado com **`0`** e `'sess_expire_on_close'` com o valor **`TRUE`**, significando que a sessão só é destruída quando o usuário fechar o navegador ou via codificação com intervenção do usuário, particularmente faço assim e nunca tive problemas.

***Link:***

- [<sub>SOen</sub> - How does Codeigniter's sess_time_to_update work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13975987/6797930)
- [Session Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)